# Selective Loading in Forge Viewer from BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have 2 questions:

1. Using Selective Loading in Forge Viewer, how can we load a particular level from a Revit Model?
2. How to load Revit model from BIM360? We need not translate the model if it's already in BIM360 right?

Answer (score 0):

1. for any properties, first get their hash key by model.getPropertyHashes() on which represents Level. With my experience, it should be p01bbdcf2. With that, compose your condition:

   ```
             '$eq': ['s.props.p01bbdcf2', "'Level 1'"] //
   ```
2. yes, BIM360 will translate the models automatically after the model is uploaded to BIM360 folder. you do not need to translate explicitly.  you can visit it directly. See this tutorial https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/